# How do I separate the dictionary list into separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary in my dataframe column of vary length:

```
categories

1) [  { "S" : "Vibes" },  { "S" : "Themed" },  { "S" : "Experiences" },  { "S" : "Girls Night" }]
2) [  { "S" : "Vibes" }]
3) [  { "S" : "Vibes" },  { "S" : "Drinks" }]
.
.
.
```

I want to make it into separate columns , if there is no dictionary on particular list it should make it as a null for that category as the output should look like :

```
categories 1          categories 2         categories 3  ......

{ "S" : "Vibes" }     { "S" : "Themed" }    { "S" : "Themed" }
{ "S" : "Vibes" }]      null                   null
.                         .                     .
.                         .                     .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode) to expand the list of dict in column `categories` into separate rows, then create the categories names ('categories 1', 'categories 2', etc) by grouping on the original row index (row index before explode) using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the serial number by [`.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) within the group.  Finally, we use [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to pivot the rows into columns.

```
df1 = df.explode('categories')
df1['Cat_Num'] = 'categories ' + df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df2 = df1.pivot(columns='Cat_Num', values='categories').rename_axis(columns=None)
```

### Demo

```
data = {'categories': [
[{ "S" : "Vibes" },  { "S" : "Themed" },  { "S" : "Experiences" },  { "S" : "Girls Night" }],
[  { "S" : "Vibes" }],
[  { "S" : "Vibes" },  { "S" : "Drinks" }]
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df.explode('categories')
df1['Cat_Num'] = 'categories ' + df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df2 = df1.pivot(columns='Cat_Num', values='categories').rename_axis(columns=None)

print(df2)



     categories 1     categories 2          categories 3          categories 4
0  {'S': 'Vibes'}  {'S': 'Themed'}  {'S': 'Experiences'}  {'S': 'Girls Night'}
1  {'S': 'Vibes'}              NaN                   NaN                   NaN
2  {'S': 'Vibes'}  {'S': 'Drinks'}                   NaN                   NaN
```